# Is a switch statement appropriate here, taking an enum?

Tags: java, oop, switch-statement

Today I was making a Tetris clone in Java, and when time came to implement the block spawning mechanism, I wrote this switch statement that takes an enum. I've been told to avoid switch statements when possible, but I'm not sure if avoiding one here is possible unless I completely overhaul my original inheritance based design choice.

To implement the different type of blocks, I decided to make an abstract super class called Block and make a child class for every specific type. I also made an enum that marks a block's type. For instance, a ZBlock extends Block object would have Type.ZBlock enum assigned to its Type field variable.

```java
private void spawnBlock(Type type){
        switch(type){
            case I:
                currentBlock = new IBlock();
                break;
            case L:
                currentBlock = new LBlock();
                break;
            case J:
                currentBlock = new JBlock();
                break;
            case Z:
                currentBlock = new ZBlock();
                break;
            case S:
                currentBlock = new SBlock();
                break;
            case T:
                currentBlock = new TBlock();
                break;
            default:
                currentBlock = new OBlock();
        }
    }
```

When I starting thinking about ways to not use a switch statement here, I couldn't think of anything other than getting rid of all of my child classes and programming the behaviors of the different blocks in a single non-abstract Block class. But it might become a mess since the different blocks have different shapes and wall kick data. So is the switch statement an ok choice here? If not, how can I improve my code and why?

Comment: "I've been told to avoid switch statements when possible". That's simply not true.

Comment: @Sweeper well he could have been told, but the person telling him is not telling him good things.

Comment: OP, `switch` is OK

Comment: why wouldn't it be appropriate? the immediate alternative I see is a lot of if else if's, and that just creates messy code. Just don't forget: switch doesn't do a null-check

Comment: *"avoid switch statements when possible"* is certainly one of the rules that "...are for the obedience of fools and the guidance of wise men". You should not avoid them at all cost. But it's certainly true that in *many* cases, `switch`-statements (and very often even `if`-statements) should be viewed with scrutiny when they refer to any sort of *type*, as in `switch(type)` or `if(type==X)`. This is certainly a red flag, and one should carefully consider whether it couldn't more properly be solved with polymorphism (which basically also was the case here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been told to avoid switch statements when possible

That is correct, but what you are doing here *might* be okay.

The point is: you don't want to have such switch statements **all over the place**. They are bad because they couple things together. And when you repeat the "same" switch pattern over and over again, that can turn into a maintenance nightmare. Because changes to your enum type ... means that you will have to look at each switch to determine if it needs to be adapted.

So, when you are able to *hide* such switching from most of your code (by doing it only in a few, ideally, one place) you are okay.

Nonetheless, a better approach could be to replace that whole switch statement with this one-liner:

```
currentBlock = type.createBlock();
```

In other words: why not put the knowledge **directly** into that enum class itself? Of course, that has other implications, such as a potential violation of the *single responsibility principle*.

But it *feels* quite natural that the enum that denotes the different types of blocks also provides a means to create such blocks (given the fact that the *type* is the only information that determines what kind of Block subclass you need).

And note: you don't necessarily *move* the *switch* into the enum. You can fully avoid switching here:

```
enum Type {
  I(IBlock::new), L(LBlock::new), ...;

  private Supplier<? extends Block> supplier;
  private Type(Supplier<? extends Block> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  public Block getBlock() {
    return supplier.get();
  }
```

( I didn't run the above through a compiler, so beware of typos )

Comment: Wow, I never even thought about writing methods into the enum class itself. I moved my switch statement there like this: public createBlock(){switch(this){...

Comment: @orchid I appreciate the quick accept, although I didnt want you to move the switch INTO the enum. See the code I just added to the answer. You can provide an instance of the Supplier interface as member of that enum, and then creating a block translates to: calling that supplier!

Comment: @orchid it's not wise, particularly if the method remained to be instance-based. Each constant now knows about all the others.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko you said "it's not wise"... What is "it"?

Comment: @orchid moving that method to the enum as an instance method

Answer (score 4):

There is another way of avoiding a `switch` case which is using a `Map` with a `EnunMap` implementation which will keep the `Type` as the key and the value as the `Block` implementation.

When dealing with `Enum` keys a `EnumMap` implementation is recommended as per the Javadoc:

> A specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys.
>
> This representation is extremely compact and efficient.
>
> Implementation note: All basic operations execute in constant time. They are likely
>   (though not guaranteed) to be faster than their HashMap counterparts.

Sample code when using a `EnumMap` in place of a `switch` where the *key* is the `Type` enum instance and the value is a `Supplier<Block>` (a constructor reference):

```
//During initialization
Map<Type, Supplier<Block>> registry =  new EnumMap<>(Type.class);
registry.put(Type.I, IBlock::new);
registry.put(Type.L, LBlock::new);
registry.put(Type.J, JBlock::new);
registry.put(Type.Z, ZBlock::new);
...
```

Then you can fetch it from the `spawnBlock()` by supplying the correct `Type` and you would get a new instance of the `Block` implementation every time due to the `Supplier.get()` call at the end:

```
private void spawnBlock(Type type){
   currentBlock = this.registry.get(type).get();
}
```

Comment: This does *not* "spawn" (as in "instantiate" `new`) blocks, but always returns the same instances. To handle this, the values of this map would/could/should be something like a `Supplier<Block>`...

Answer (score 4):

Switch is better than using if-else statements. In my opinion it is much cleaner code.
Just compare it with the same code using if-else:

```
private void spawnBlock(Type type){
    if(Type.I.equals(type)) {
        currentBlock = new IBlock();
    } else if(Type.L.equals(type)) {
        currentBlock = new LBlock();
    } else if(Type.J.equals(type)) {
        currentBlock = new JBlock();
    } else if(Type.Z.equals(type)) {
        currentBlock = new ZBlock();
    } else if(Type.S.equals(type)) {
        currentBlock = new SBlock();
    } else if(Type.T.equals(type)) {
        currentBlock = new TBlock();
    } else {
        currentBlock = new OBlock();
    }
}
```

But often you have the chance to use a different approach than switch or if-else.
Just take a look at the other answers or look at [this](https://schneide.blog/2010/12/13/avoid-switch-use-enum/). It explains how you can improve your code using enum and putting the logic directly into the enum.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have an enum, let each constant know how to create an instance of the type it represents.

```
interface Block {}
class IBlock implements Block {}
class LBlock implements Block {}

enum  Type {
  I(IBlock::new), 
  L(LBlock::new);

  private Supplier<? extends Block> blockSupplier;

  Type(Supplier<? extends Block> supplier) {
    blockSupplier =supplier;
  }

  public Supplier<? extends Block> getBlockSupplier() {
    return blockSupplier;
  }
}
```

A method that spawns blocks would look like

```
private void spawnBlock(Type type) {
  currentBlock = type.getBlockSupplier().get();
}
```

With that said, I don't see problems with the switch approach here. A more alarming thing is that the method has a side effect: it doesn't produce a new `Block` (which I would go with), it sets the field. What to expect from a method named `spawnBlock` that returns nothing?

Comment: Any reason to expose the `Supplier` as such, and not just hide it and offer its functionality via a `type.createBlock()` method?

Comment: @Marco13 just to let the caller decide when to create an object

Comment: Obtaining the supplier exposes an "implementation detail". It makes the `call().somewhat().longer()`. Nobody can have a valid reason to obtain the supplier, *unless* he wants to create an instance. (And if someone wants a `Supplier` instance, e.g. to pass it around, he can still create a `Supplier<Block> supplier = type::createBlock` method reference). Sorry, I don't see a reason to do it like that...

Comment: @Marco13 the point is in lazy initialisation, and it's not very clear here because we call `get` right after we obtain `type.getBlockSupplier()`. Imagine you are preparing to create a block, and suddenly the user got a bonus which changes the type of next block/pauses the game for 10 seconds/finishes the game/etc. You dispose of the supplier and move on.

Comment: @Marco13 Obtaining a supplier implies you *may* want to create an object. But it doesn't necessarily mean you will create one.

Comment: @Marco13 you probably read @Cat's answer before reading mine... No, it doesn't "expose an "implementation detail"". You still have no idea what `Block` I will give you, you don't know how I store it and where it comes from.

Comment: Sorry, it may be a detail, and we don't have to argue about extensively, but the arguments do not convince me. The main counterargument is: 1.: What you want to do is create a block, and not obtain a supplier. And 2.: **Iff** you want a supplier, for whatever reason, then the method that creates the block **is** a supplier, via a method reference. (Not intended to be sarcastic, but a bit tounge-in-cheek: You could also let the supplier return a `BlockFactory` with a `createBlock` method, to add another level of the same kind of indirection... no offense, I just don't see the point...)

Comment: @Marco13 we aren't arguing, we are having a chat :) Maybe you are right, I didn't give much thought while posting it. 1) It's not always that straightforward. You may or may not want to create a block *under certain conditions* (as I mentioned above) 2) the method is not a supplier, but `() -> theMethod(type)` is (or, as you said, a method reference to it). If you want a supplier, why would you need to wrap the method call in a supplier every time, if you could simply return a supplier? (I am not defending my answer in any way, just saying how I see it)